::error::self-signed certificate in certificate chain, while testing a java action locally using act
I am trying to test a java action locally using act & my action uses the setup-java@v4 action from the github marketplace like below:
uses: actions/setup-java@v4
with:
  distribution: "adopt"
  java-version: '21'

I am getting this error "::error::self-signed certificate in certificate chain" & it is failing the workflow.
I have tried searching all over the internet but nothing helped. Any suggestions on how to fix this?
